# Парсинг ссылок регулярным выражением

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Если парсить ссылку и делить на переменные именованными подмасками, например, то что будет заключаться в следующие блоки:

```
[a-z0-9]{8}-(?:[a-z0-9]{4}-){3}[a-z0-9]{12}

(?:[^/]+/)+

[^/]*
```

Что разделит preg_match в данном случае, если на вход поступает url, в сравнении с parse_url, и есть такое выражение:

```
!/?(?P<id>[a-z0-9]{8}-(?:[a-z0-9]{4}-){3}[a-z0-9]{12})(?:/(?:-/(?P<effects>(?:[^/]+/)+)))?(?<file>[^/]*)!
```

P.S. regex101, видимо, пользоваться не умею, раз он ничего не выдает.

Также нужно объяснение, как именно это парсится.

Comment: Прочитал вопрос дважды. Ничего не понял. Что надо объяснять? Принцип работы конечного автомата регулярных выражений? Синтаксис PCRE?

Comment: Что выходит в итоге, если на вход такой регулярки попадет ссылка, и почему именно так.

Comment: @Timur Musharapov регулярка - это не всезабивающий молоток. Такую работу она выполнит некачественно и будет неотлаживаема. Пользуйтесь `parse_url` , или аналогичным функционалом фреймворков.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[a-z0-9]{8}-(?:[a-z0-9]{4}-){3}[a-z0-9]{12}
```

Как следует из полного регулярного выражения - это некий ID.
Условно буду называть `[a-z0-9]` - буквой.
Итак, имеем восемь букв, литерал `-`, три раза по четыре буквы с литералом `-` после них, двенадцать букв. Пример строки:

```
aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Буквы могут меняться, а их количество строго определено.

---

Следующая часть - "эффекты". Этот элемент не обязателен.
Возможно, хотели написать что-то сложное, потом запутались, ошиблись и в итоге получилось, что для выделения "эффектов" перед ними должны быть литералы `/-/` и эффект обязательно должен заканчиваться на литерал `/`. нет слэша- нет эффекта.
Примеры:

```
/-/asd/
/-/asd/asd/
```

Не "эффект" (между слэшами нет литералов):

```
/-/asd/asd//asd/
```

---

Если есть "эффект", то все литералы после него отличные от `/` считаются "файлом", если "эффекта" нет, то все литералы после ID, отличные от `/`, считаются "файлом".
Примеры:

```
что угодно, кроме слэша
```

---

Примеры полных строк:
Есть ID, эффект, нет файла:

```
aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa/-/effect/effect/
```

Есть ID, есть файл, нет эффекта:

```
aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaafile
```

---

"Поиграть" с разным текстом можно здесь:
https://regex101.com/r/eiDJtX/1

---

**UPD** Ух ты. regex101 нехило прокачали и теперь там можно добавлять сразу много тестов для регулярного выражения:

https://regex101.com/r/eiDJtX/2/tests

Answer (score 2):

Это регулярное выражение по идеи несёт полнейшую безсмыслицу, тут нету ничего общего с parse_url, потому что регулярное выражение не соответствует стандарту формирования URL\URI